# Where to get players/DM's to review my campaign ideas/plot?

Tags: dnd-5e, campaign-development

I am a new DM on DnD 5e. I have DM'd a bit of Lost Mines of Phandalver, and played some DnD. But recently, I created a new campaign for my players.

I made a map (thank you, Gimp), created a backstory, made a world, and the players (first timers, but enjoy fantasy) had fun, and they want more.

What I would like is a place where I can spell out my story and plot ideas and get feedback on it. Is it good, does it work, what can I do better, what are possible points of failure?

Here's a skeleton plot:

- The world is relatively 'young' and unexplored.
- Humans and Drow are rivals. They are both expansionist, hence they clashed, waged a costly war, ended in ceasefire.
- Henceforth, Human/ Drow areas of interest were marked, and in between them were buffer states with halflings, Elves, etc.
- Now, human population growth being what it is (and a 'loose' immigration policy) means that Humans need to expand. Drow and Humans
  agree on a colony location for Humans.
- This colony prospers. Looks like it's getting rich on mines and wheat.
- Enter goblins. Thieves, they've been stealing weapons/ iron/ ore.
- Enter adventurers.
- Goblins are evil? Kill em!
- here's where I introduce complexity - Goblins are tribes, some tribes are being dominated by the Drow, who want to use them as
  proxys to raid humans and whittle down their new colony.
- Some goblin tribes don't want to join Drow (loss of independence, exploitation concerns), but they're hard pressed in battle. They look
  to humans for concessions.
- Humans are plagued by a distrust of goblins (due to having fought their southern cousins..) so who knows if they'll make concessions.

And that's as far as I've got.

Comment: This question will likely be closed as either opinion based or too broad.  Not all questions are a good fit for the SE format, and some may be better posed at a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/22566).  The linked meta question has some forums that SE members have found to be helpful. This isn't anything bad, it's just a constraint of the SE format.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to get an idea of what questions fit best here.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen quite a few people ask for feedback on the appropriate Reddit pages.

Giant in the playground (Neat collection of RPG oriented comics) has an impressive forum, with a dedicated section for [homebrew](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?15-Homebrew-Design).